# Remove cells when searchBar text is above 0

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uisearchcontroller

i've created a tableView which i first did set to that it should use the filtered array if the searchController was active. However i want to first do it when the searchBar contain more than 0 characters. However this does not seem to work. Here is what i've done so far in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
    if (count(self.teamSearchController.searchBar.text) > 0) {
        team = filteredTableData[indexPath.row] as Team
        cell.textLabel?.text = team.name as String

    } else {
        team = self.teamArray[indexPath.row] as Team
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 20)
        cell.textLabel?.text = team.name as String

    }
```

updateSearchResultsForSearchController

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController)
{



    filteredTableData.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "name CONTAINS[c] %@ OR shortname CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text, searchController.searchBar.text)
    let array = (teamArray as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate) as! [Team]
    filteredTableData = array

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: What is not working? Are you reloading the table view when the searchBar text changes?

Comment: yes in updateSearchResultsForSearchController. when i press UISearchBar it seem to show the filteredTableData. i want it to use that when the searchBar contain more than 0 characters

Comment: Show your update code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do the checking for length of search text in `updateSearchResultsForSearchController`

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController)
{

    if searchController.searchBar.text == "" {
        filteredTableData = self.teamArray      
    } else {
        filteredTableData.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

        let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "name CONTAINS[c] %@ OR shortname CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text, searchController.searchBar.text)

        let array = (teamArray as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate) as! [Team]
        filteredTableData = array
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Update the code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` as shown below, just have a check if the searchController is active or not

```
if (self.teamSearchController.active) {
    team = filteredTableData[indexPath.row] as Team

} else {
    team = self.teamArray[indexPath.row] as Team
    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 20)
}
cell.textLabel?.text = team.name as String
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not good design to query the search bar in every table view cell. Instead, have only one array that the table view displays.

Whenever the search bar contents change, change the content of the array to be displayed in the table to the filtered array. Handle your edge case in the update method. I think the if statement you wrote should work fine.

Comment: i'm not quite sure what you mean could u make a snippet or seudo code